# Accessible and styleable button in React Native Web?

Tags: react-native-web

I need to have a "button" as in a clickable element that performs an action. On the web I would normally use an actual button element: `<button>Click me</button>`

However in React Native the Button component isn't very stylable, so most people use another element eg TouchableOpacity.

If I use TouchableOpacity then React Native Web does set `data-focusable="true"` and `tabindex="0"`, however it doesn't set the role to be button. Is it therefore not ideal in terms of accessibility? If so, then is there a more accessable way to have buttons in React Native Web?

Comment: Did you find an answer ?